# JJC JF-U wireless trigger does not trigger flash at the right moment

Tags: off-camera-flash, wireless-triggers, nikon-d5600

I am trying to take a photo with my camera and trigger an off camera flash all wirelessly with the following setup:

A Nikon D5600 and a Metz B520-AF flash which I'm trying to use with a JJC wireless trigger kit (like this one http://www.jjc.cc/index.php/Product/product_info/id/575). On one of the receivers I attach my flash while the other one is connected to the camera with a trigger cable. I have to use manual mode on the flash because TTL mode is not supported by the trigger kit. When I press the button of the transmitter the flash fires and the camera takes a photo.
The problem is that the flash and camera don't appear to be synchronized - no light from the flash seems to be present at the time of taking the photo and my photos turn out dark. The only way I manage to get it to work is when I have the transmitter attached on top of the camera and I press the button of the camera itself but this effectively defeats my purpose.

If someone could point out what I am doing wrong or explain how I could get it to work I would be eternally grateful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably not doing anything wrong. It's that the JJC triggers can't tell what they're being used for, and both receivers are getting the transmitter signal at the same time, and tripping the shutter release and flash burst at the same time. The shutter release has to happen *before* the flash burst.

If you stick with these triggers, you need another transmitter: so you have one transmitter and receiver set to use as a shutter remote on one channel, and one set to use as flash triggers, set to a different channel.  That way, the flash receivers don't trigger at the same time as the shutter.

Or, you could return those triggers, and replace them with transceivers (a unit that can be either a transmitter or a receiver) that are programmed to have a delay between receiving a shutter release signal and sending a flash sync signal in a single unit, like the Yongnuo RF-603 II, RF-605, or Flashpoint SPT.

Comment: To put it another way, the set you have can be used to trigger the camera remotely *or* to trigger the flash from the camera. But it can't be used to do *both* at the same time.

Comment: I understand what's going on now! I guess I will get one of the recommended alternative units and try again. Thank you so much guys and stay safe!

Comment: @Kremi, if you do get one of the listed alternatives, and you're in the US and able to order from Adorama as it's exclusive to them, I'd say go for [the Flashpoint SPT](https://www.adorama.com/fprrr2spt.html). It ties into the much larger [Godox X system](http://flashhavoc.com/godox-flash-system-overview/), if you ever need to expand your lighting options.